# Find the number of integer solutions of $22x^2-34xy+6y^2=2024$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I was given this and I could really use some hints. I know that there are no integer solutions to the equation and that I have to factor the left side to get the form $(ax+by)^2$ by multiplying/dividing both sides of the equation and/or perhaps use a prime modulo of some sort so that I get a congruence in the form of $w^2\equiv c$ and then check that c is not a quadratic residue of the modulo and so reach the conclusion that there are no integer solutions to the problem. I have tried modules 3-37 (maybe made some mistakes along the way) and tried diving by 2 and then adding the modulo and haven't gotten even close to the right answer. Perhaps someone could push me toward the right modulo or give me a hint of what to look for.

Comment: Tiny hint:  Make the numbers easier to work with by dividing both sides of the equation by 2.

Comment: I tried that too, but sadly it didn't help much. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Treat the expression as a quadratic in $x.$ Solving for $x$ will give you an expression that has to be the square of an integer if the equation admits any integral solutions. Using modulo $157$ (iirc), you will be able to show that no integral solutions exist. This method is sort of tedious, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by 6 gives you $(6y-17x)^2-157x^2=12144$.

But quadratic reciprocity gives you $\left(\dfrac{12144}{157}\right)=-1$, so this equation admits no integral solution.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious minor simplification to the equation is to observe that all of the coefficients are even, so let's divide by 2.

$$11x^2-17xy+3y^2=1012$$

Let's try your modulo arithmetic approach, and use a computer program to help us.

```
def eqmod(a, b, c):
   '''
   Check if a is congruent to b modulo c.
   '''
   return (a - b) % c == 0

def solvemod(m):
   '''
   Return a set of (x, y) pairs that satisfy the equation
   11x^2 - 17xy + 3y^2 = 1012, modulo m.
   '''
   return {
       (x, y)
       for x in range(m)
       for y in range(m)
       if eqmod(11 * x ** 2 - 17 * x * y + 3 * y ** 2, 1012, m)
   }
```

I went ahead and computed all of the solutions sets for moduli up to 1000.

It turns out that if you pick $m = 157$ (or any multiple of 157), then there are *no* possible solutions.  And $m = 529 = 23^2$ has no solutions either, despite not being a multiple of 157.  So if you're willing to accept a brute-force computer proof, just do the arithmetic modulo 157 or 529.

Alternatively, we could use the largest modulus for which there is exactly *one* solution using modular arithmetic.  That works out to $m = 46$, which has the solution $x = y = 0$.  IOW, $x = 46p$ and $y = 46q$, where $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Making this substitution gives:

$$11(46p)^2 - 17(46p)(46q) + 3(46q)^2 = 1012$$
$$46^2(11p^2 - 17pq + 3q^2) = 1012$$
$$11p^2 - 17pq + 3q^2 = \frac{11}{23}$$

So we have an integer on one side of the equation, and an non-integer on the other.  That doesn't work.